# Angular 5 Material autocomplete has null initial value

Tags: angular, autocomplete, rxjs, angular-material2, rxjs5

I have an autocomplete form field which works fine when it is a simple autocomplete.  However, when I try to add a custom filter, it fails.

The data for the autocomplete is coming from a parent component. The parent component has:

```js
alldwgrevdata: Observable<DrawingRevisionIDsOnly[]>;
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.alldwgrevdata = this.drawingRevisionService.getAllDrawingRevisions();
}
```

and passes the data to the child in the template by:

```html
<child [alldwgrevdata]="alldwgrevdata | async"></child>
```

The service returns `Observable<DrawingRevisionIDsOnly[]>`.

The child is set up like this:

```js
export class DrawingSelectorComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input("drawingrevs")
    drawingrevs: DrawingRevision[] = [];

    @Input("alldwgrevdata")
    alldwgrevdata: DrawingRevisionIDsOnly[] = [];

    filteredrevdata: Observable<DrawingRevisionIDsOnly[]>;

    @Input()
    public parentForm: FormGroup;

    @Output()
    onDwgChange = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private drawingRevisionService: DrawingRevisionService, private messagesService: MessagesService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.alldwgrevdata);
        let dwgSelectControl = new FormControl(this.drawingrevs);
        this.parentForm.addControl('attachedDwgsControl', dwgSelectControl);

        this.filteredrevdata = dwgSelectControl.valueChanges
            .startWith([])
            .map(dwgrev => dwgrev && typeof dwgrev === 'object' ? (dwgrev.drawingID+" "+dwgrev.revisionid) : dwgrev)
            .map(dwgIDrevID => dwgIDrevID ? this.filter(dwgIDrevID) : this.alldwgrevdata.slice());
    }

    filter(dwgIDrevID: string): DrawingRevisionIDsOnly[] {
        return this.alldwgrevdata.filter(option => (option.drawingID+" "+option.revisionid).toLowerCase().indexOf(dwgIDrevID.toLowerCase()) === 0);
    }

    displayFn(dwgRev: DrawingRevisionIDsOnly): string {
        return dwgRev ? (dwgRev.drawingID+" "+dwgRev.revisionid) : "";
    }
}
```

The error is `this.alldwgrevdata is null`.  In the ngOnInit() method, the console.log does indeed output `null`, so the error makes sense to some degree.  The problem comes when setting the `valueChanges` part of the form control.

I tried to change

```js
this.alldwgrevdata.slice()
```

to

```js
(this.alldwgrevdata==null ? [] : this.alldwgrevdata.slice())
```

but that had no effect.

How can I either set an initial value for the Observable to an empty array, or force the valueChanges to wait until the data service is complete before being evaluated?  Or is there a completely different way to go about this which I am missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```js
.map(dwgIDrevID => dwgIDrevID ? this.filter(dwgIDrevID) : this.alldwgrevdata.slice());
```

can branch either way. If branching to  `this.filter()` (which also uses `this.alldwgrevdata`) you will get the same error message.

The problem is, on this line

```html
<child [alldwgrevdata]="alldwgrevdata | async"></child>
```

the value passed in will initially be null, and the default empty array used here

```js
@Input("alldwgrevdata")
alldwgrevdata: DrawingRevisionIDsOnly[] = [];
```

will be over-ridden by that null. (Defaults only happen if the parameter is not passed in).

Instead of testing for null in lots of places, you could use @Input in combination with `set/get` syntax, and default null value to `[]` inside the set.

```js
private _alldwgrevdata = [];
@Input('alldwgrevdata')
set alldwgrevdata(value: string) {
  this._alldwgrevdata = value || [];
}
get alldwgrevdata() {
  return this._alldwgrevdata;
}
```

Comment: Although I didn't end up needing to use this approach, your answer got me thinking about some things that I hadn't been focusing on before, and I eventually got it working.  Thanks!